# How to serialize declarative links (jersey) with jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jersey, jackson

I am using declarative linking in my project. My jackson mapper configuration is

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, false);
    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_FIELDS, false);
    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_IS_GETTERS, false);
    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_GETTERS, false);
    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_SETTERS, false);
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
```

As I have disabled any kind of auto detection, injected links like

```
    @InjectLinks({

@InjectLink(rel = "bookmark", resource = ConnectionsResource.class, style = Style.ABSOLUTE_PATH) })
@JsonProperty("links")
Link[] links;
```

are serialized to an empty JSON object (because none of the fields in "Link" is annotated with `@JsonProperty`).

How to enable serialization for Links only for the fields `rel` and `href` without changing my global mapper configuration?

Comment: Is this Jersey 2.x and is the `Link` type `javax.ws.rs.core.Link`?

Comment: Which JSON provider are you using? I'd like to test it

Comment: `<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId><artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>`

Comment: So is the problem that all the values are empty, or is the problem just too many unnecessary fields. Because I can't reproduce the former. I can reproduce the latter, and have a solution for it

Comment: The problem is that the mapper is configured to exclude ALL fields but the marked ones (`@JsonProperty`). This setting can't be changed. The fields exposed by the `Link` class are not marked, and are therefore not serialized as json. The resulting JSON only contains `"links":[{},{},...]`

Comment: Are you allowed to _add_ anything the ObjectMapper configuration?

Comment: No, but I can use my own ObjectMapper. The problem is the whole project was build assuming that only annotated fields get serialized. If I change the auto detection settings, I have to touch every single class to add  ignore annotations to the currently unannotated fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So one way to make this work is to use a customer serializer. You would have to add a new module for this serializer to the `ObjectMapper`, but this should not effect the rest of the configurations.

Here's the serializer

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Link;

public class LinkSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Link>{

    @Override
    public void serialize(Link link, JsonGenerator jg, SerializerProvider sp) 
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jg.writeStartObject();
        jg.writeStringField("rel", link.getRel());
        jg.writeStringField("href", link.getUri().toString());
        jg.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Here a test class

```
public class TestClass {

    @JsonProperty("links")
    protected List<Link> links;
    protected String name;
    protected String id;
    // getter and setters
}
```

And the test run

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, false);
    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_FIELDS, false);
    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_IS_GETTERS, false);
    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_GETTERS, false);
    mapper.configure(MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_SETTERS, false);
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);

    SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
    simpleModule.addSerializer(Link.class, new LinkSerializer());
    mapper.registerModule(simpleModule);

    Link link1 = Link.fromUri(URI.create("http://localhost:8080/")).rel("one").build();
    Link link2 = Link.fromUri(URI.create("http://localhost:8080/")).rel("two").build();
    TestClass test = new TestClass();
    test.getLinks().add(link1);
    test.getLinks().add(link2);
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(test);
    System.out.println(json);
}
```

produces this result

```
{
  "links" : [ {
    "rel" : "one",
    "href" : "http://localhost:8080/"
  }, {
    "rel" : "two",
    "href" : "http://localhost:8080/"
  } ]
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the `LinkSerializer `.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of using the Jackson mixin annotation for serializing and deserializing the `Link` object including all the properties:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(
        fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
        getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
        isGetterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
@JsonDeserialize(using = LinkMixin.LinkDeserializer.class)
public abstract class LinkMixin extends Link {

    private static final String HREF = "href";

    @JsonProperty(HREF)
    @Override
    public abstract URI getUri();

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public abstract Map<String, String> getParams();

    public static class LinkDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Link> {

        @Override
        public Link deserialize(
                final JsonParser p,
                final DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
            final Map<String, String> params = p.readValueAs(
                    new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {});
            if (params == null) {
                return null;
            }
            final String uri = params.remove(HREF);
            if (uri == null) {
                return null;
            }
            final Builder builder = Link.fromUri(uri);
            params.forEach(builder::param);
            return builder.build();
        }
    }
}
```