# jersey declarative hyperlinking customizing the resulting url

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

I've managed to get jersey declarative hyperlinking working, however, I would like to have the result of this code:

```
@InjectLink(resource = UserResource.class, method="getUserApplications",  bindings ={@Binding(name = "id", value = "${instance.id}")}, style =  InjectLink.Style.ABSOLUTE)
private String applications;
```

Be this:

```
    "account": {
    "applications":{ "href":"https://localhost:8080/IMREST/api/accounts/55fb111629d40123a811ad0e/applications"}
}
```

instead of this:

```
    "account": {
    "applications" : "http://localhost:8080/IMREST/api/accounts/55fb111629d40123a811ad0e/applications"
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can accomplish this?

I was thinking that I could possibly extend the @InjectLink interface, but I'm not sure that will work. I'm currently using JacksonFeature in Glassfish to marshall my model objects and the only customization I've seen so far with Declarative Hyperlinking has been to use Wrapper Objects.  I'd prefer to avoid that route.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who's looking, I found the answer [here from peeskillet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26989004/how-to-serialize-declarative-links-jersey-with-jackson) on another question(second answer).

TL;DR
I needed to implement a LinkSerializer which I did as a module thusly:

```
public class LinkSerializerModule extends SimpleModule {

    public LinkSerializerModule() {
        super("LinkSerializerModule", new Version(0, 1, 0, "alpha", "net.galtech.id", "IMREST"));
        this.addSerializer(Link.class, new LinkSerializer());
    }

    public class LinkSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Link> {

        @Override
        public void serialize(Link link, JsonGenerator jg, SerializerProvider sp)
                throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            jg.writeStartObject();
            jg.writeStringField("href", link.getUri().toString());
            jg.writeEndObject();
        }
    }
}
```